# eigs MATLAB to R language (complex matrix)

Tags: r, matlab

In R language (RSpectra/rARPACK library) you can find a function **eigs()** - similar to MATLAB eigs() - but not running with complex matrix in input. Where can I find in R language a function eigs() completely corresponding to the MATLAB one with the generalized option too?

```
> set.seed(123)  
> n = 100     # matrix size  
> k = 5       # number of eigenvalues to calculate  
> M = matrix(rnorm(n^2), n)  
> A = crossprod(M)      # Make it symmetric  
>   
> library(RSpectra)  
> res = eigs(A, k)   
> res$values  
[1] 391 367 354 323 315  
> head(res$vectors)  
        [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]    [,5]  
[1,] -0.1298  0.01131 -0.000102  0.08849  0.0504  
[2,]  0.0669 -0.00101  0.010345 -0.00941 -0.0799  
[3,]  0.0533  0.05726  0.099891 -0.17171  0.0133  
[4,] -0.1342  0.16530  0.007646 -0.00679  0.1025  
[5,]  0.1302  0.01915  0.042567 -0.16027 -0.0625  
[6,]  0.0663  0.05346  0.032320 -0.07483 -0.1637  
> A=as.complex(A)  
> res = eigs(A, k)   
Error in UseMethod("eigs") :   
  no applicable method for 'eigs' applied to an object of class "complex"
```

Comment: use `eigen()`? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eigen.html. Should also work with complex input.

Comment: Note that `as.complex` returns a vector. Use `Ac <- as.complex(A); 
dim(Ac) <- dim(A)` to get a matrix. But that doesn't change that `eigs` only works for values of type numeric.

Comment: eigen() doesn't return a subset of generalized eigenvector/eigenvalues...

Comment: Does anybody know where I can find MATLAB eigs()  - if not in R - almost in c++ language?